# One row of data can't be shown

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image: Check this]

I am a newbie to this and i have no idea why nothing is shown on the "Detail" tab but i did successfully insert data into the database. Could some one help me on this?

```
<?php
require ("Data/TaxiData.php");


class TaxiController {

function CreateOverviewTable() {
    $result = "
        <table class='overViewTable'>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><b>Id</b></td>
                <td><b>Name</b></td>
                <td><b>Gender</b></td>
                <td><b>Faculty</b></td>
                <td><b>CarType</b></td>
                <td><b>Car Plate Number</b></td>
                <td><b>Price</b></td>
                <td><b>Detail</b></td>
            </tr>";

    $itaxiArray = $this->GetitaxiByType('%');

    foreach ($itaxiArray as $key => $value) {
        $result = $result .
                "<tr>
                    <td><a href='Add.html?update=$value->id'>Update</a></td>
                    <td><a href='#' onclick='showConfirm($value->id)'>Delete</a></td>
                    <td>$value->id</td>
                    <td>$value->name</td>
                    <td>$value->gender</td>    
                    <td>$value->faculty</td> 
                    <td>$value->type</td>
                    <td>$value->plate</td>
                    <td>$value->price</td>
                    <td>$value->detail</td>
                </tr>";
    }

    $result = $result . "</table>";
    return $result;
}

function CreateitaxiDropdownList() {
    $TaxiData = new TaxiData();
    $result = "<form action = '' method = 'post' width = '200px'>
                Please select a type: 
                <select name = 'types' >
                    <option value = '%' >All</option>
                    " . $this->CreateOptionValues($this->GetitaxiTypes()) .
            "</select>
                 <input type = 'submit' value = 'Search' />
                </form>";

    return $result;
}

function CreateOptionValues(array $valueArray) {
    $result = "";

    foreach ($valueArray as $value) {
        $result = $result . "<option value='$value'>$value</option>";
    }

    return $result;
}

function CreateitaxiTables($types) {
    $TaxiData = new TaxiData();
    $itaxiArray = $TaxiData->GetitaxiByType($types);
    $result = "";


    foreach ($itaxiArray as $key => $itaxi) {
        $result = $result .
                "<table class = 'itaxiTable'>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan='6' width = '150px' ><img runat = 'server' src = '$itaxi->image' /></th>
                        <th width = '75px' >Name: </th>
                        <td>$itaxi->name</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th>Gender: </th>
                        <td>$itaxi->gender</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th>Faculty: </th>
                        <td>$itaxi->faculty</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th>Car type: </th>
                        <td>$itaxi->type</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th>Car Plate: </th>
                        <td>$itaxi->plate</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th>Detail: </th>
                        <td>$itaxi->detail</td>
                    </tr>


                 </table>";
    }
    return $result;
}

function GetImages() {

    $handle = opendir("Images/ump");


    while ($image = readdir($handle)) {
        $images[] = $image;
    }

    closedir($handle);


    $imageArray = array();
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        if (strlen($image) > 2) {
            array_push($imageArray, $image);
        }
    }


    $result = $this->CreateOptionValues($imageArray);
    return $result;
}   



function Insertitaxi() {
    $name = $_POST["txtName"];
    $gender = $_POST["txtGender"];
    $faculty = $_POST["txtFaculty"];
    $type = $_POST["txtCar Type"];
    $plate = $_POST["txtCar Plate Number"];
    $price = $_POST["txtPrice"];
    $detail = $_POST["txtDetail"];


    $itaxi = new TaxiEntity(-1, $name, $gender, $faculty, $type, $plate, $price);
    $TaxiData = new TaxiData();
    $TaxiData->Insertitaxi($itaxi);
}

function Updateitaxi($id) {
   $name = $_POST["txtName"];
    $gender = $_POST["txtGender"];
    $faculty = $_POST["txtFaculty"];
    $type = $_POST["ddlCar Type"];
    $plate = $_POST["txtCar Plate Number"];
    $price = $_POST["txtPrice"];
     $detail = $_POST["txtDetail"];

     $itaxi = new TaxiEntity(-1, $name, $gender, $faculty, $type, $plate, $price, $detail);
    $TaxiData = new TaxiData();
    $TaxiData->Updateitaxi($id, $itaxi);
}

function Deleteitaxi($id) 
{
    $TaxiData = new TaxiData();
    $TaxiData->Deleteitaxi($id);
}


function GetitaxiById($id) {
   $TaxiData = new TaxiData();
    return $TaxiData->GetitaxiById($id);
}

function GetitaxiByType($type) {
   $TaxiData = new TaxiData();
    return $TaxiData->GetitaxiByType($type);
}

function GetitaxiTypes() {
  $TaxiData = new TaxiData();
    return $TaxiData->GetitaxiTypes();
}

}
?>
```

So, this is TaxiData.php. Maybe something's going wrong here too.

```
    <?php
```

require ("Entities/TaxiEntity.php");

class TaxiData {

```
function GetitaxiTypes() {
    require ('mysql_connect.php');

    mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db_name);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT type FROM itaxi") or die(mysql_error());
    $types = array();


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($types, $row[0]);
    }


    mysql_close();
    return $types;
}


function GetitaxiByType($type) {
    require ('mysql_connect.php');

    mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
     mysql_select_db($db_name);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM itaxi WHERE type LIKE '$type'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $TaxiArray = array();


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row[0];
        $name = $row[1];
        $gender = $row[2];
        $faculty = $row[3];
        $type = $row[4];
        $plate = $row[5];
        $price = $row[6];
        $detail = $row[7];



      $itaxi = new TaxiEntity($id, $name, $gender, $faculty, $type, $plate, $price, $detail);
        array_push($TaxiArray, $itaxi);
    }

    mysql_close();
    return $TaxiArray;
}

function GetitaxiById($id) {
    require ('mysql_connect.php');

     mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
     mysql_select_db($db_name);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM itaxi WHERE id = $id";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $name = $row[1];
        $gender = $row[2];
        $faculty = $row[3];
        $type = $row[4];
        $plate = $row[5];
        $price = $row[6];
        $detail = $row[7];


       $itaxi = new TaxiEntity($id, $name, $gender, $faculty, $type, $plate, $price, $detail);
    }

    mysql_close();
    return $itaxi;
}

function Insertitaxi(TaxiEntity $itaxi) {
    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO itaxi
                      (name, gender, faculty,type,plate,price,detail)
                      VALUES
                      ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",
            mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->name),
            mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->gender),
            mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->faculty),
            mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->type),
            mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->plate),
            mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->price),
             mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->detail));
    $this->PerformQuery($query);
}

function Updateitaxi($id, TaxiEntity $itaxi) {
    $query = sprintf("UPDATE itaxi
                        SET name = '%s', gender = '%s', faculty = '%s', type = '%s',
                        price = '%s', detail = '%s'
                      WHERE id = $id",
           mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->name),
            mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->gender),
            mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->faculty),
            mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->type),
            mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->plate),
            mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->price),
             mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->detail));

    $this->PerformQuery($query);
}

function Deleteitaxi($id) {
    $query = "DELETE FROM itaxi WHERE id = $id";
    $this->PerformQuery($query);
}

function PerformQuery($query) {
   require ('mysql_connect.php');

     mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
     mysql_select_db($db_name);


    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_close();
}
```

}
?>

Thanks!

Update:
This is the database 
[image: database]

This is what i get after debugging
[image: outcome of debugging]

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Try to explain yourself a bit, we just have a lot of code with no idea of what you're trying to do !

Comment: I dont know what TaxiData.php is doing, but there is the answer

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear. I'm trying to display the data from the database to the webpage. All the rows are doing fine just that the data from "Detail" cant be shown.

Comment: @ A.blub TaxiData is for retrieving data

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your missing a bit of code

```
function Insertitaxi() {
    $name = $_POST["txtName"];
    $gender = $_POST["txtGender"];
    $faculty = $_POST["txtFaculty"];
    $type = $_POST["txtCar Type"];
    $plate = $_POST["txtCar Plate Number"];
    $price = $_POST["txtPrice"];
    $detail = $_POST["txtDetail"];


    $itaxi = new TaxiEntity(-1, $name, $gender, $faculty, $type, $plate, $price);
    $TaxiData = new TaxiData();
    $TaxiData->Insertitaxi($itaxi);
}
```

The line
 `$itaxi = new TaxiEntity(-1, $name, $gender, $faculty, $type, $plate, $price);` 
looks like it should be
 `$itaxi = new TaxiEntity(-1, $name, $gender, $faculty, $type, $plate, $price, $detail);`

Just missing the field $detail on the end by the looks of it. Give it a try.

Update -
Also try fixing  the missing plate on your other function -

```
function Updateitaxi($id, TaxiEntity $itaxi) {
    $query = sprintf("UPDATE itaxi
                        SET name = '%s', gender = '%s', faculty = '%s', type = '%s',
                        price = '%s', detail = '%s'
                      WHERE id = $id",
           mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->name),
            mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->gender),
            mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->faculty),
            mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->type),
            mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->plate),
            mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->price),
             mysql_real_escape_string($itaxi->detail));

    $this->PerformQuery($query);
}
```

Change the update to include plate = %s

```
"UPDATE itaxi SET name = '%s', gender = '%s', faculty = '%s', type = '%s', plate = '%s', price = '%s', detail = '%s' WHERE id = $id",
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77805/discussion-on-answer-by-user3257693-one-row-of-data-cant-be-shown).